# linux - how to copy files/folders without permissions

Tags: linux

I have a problem copying files from my android device(sd card) to my pc(linux)

problem is the following:
because on sdcard all files and folders has ---rwxr-x permissions I can't copy a folder with files inside because it retains permissions so I can't write in that folder, and then I have to manually set permissions to that folder and then manually copy files.

So my question is is there a way to copy files and folders but without retaining their original permissions?

Comment: it's not possible, but you can launch `cp` command as super user. it will works properly. `sudo cp -r source target`

Comment: yes of course, I forgot about that, thanks

Comment: Doesn't `cp -va source target` work? How about `tar -c source | tar -x --directory target`?

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you need `sudo` to perform that. Otherwise you can use [pmount](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/pmount.1.html) which will basically mount your sdcard so that you can write to it without requiring su privileges (and also do not require them for mounting), which can be very practical in the long term.